# Repeat different shape Tensors along nth dimension

Tags: python-3.x, torch

I have three tensors of different shapes/dimensions and I want to always repeat them along the first dimension. But I get a *RuntimeError: Number of dimensions of repeat dims can not be smaller than number of dimensions of tensor*.

I understand what the error is telling me and I know how to repeat each tensor on its own (.repeat(n,), .repeat(n,1,), .repeat(n,1,1)) but I would like to be able to do it in one call.

Something along the lines of .repeat(3,*)

For example:

```
n = 3
x = torch.rand((3,))
y = torch.rand((3,10))
z = torch.rand((3,10,5))

# these work 
x.repeat(n,) 
y.repeat(n,1)
z.repeat(n,1,1) 


# this does not
z.repeat(n,)
```